# Storing web audio processed data from a custom worklet to turn into wav file

Tags: web-audio-api

I was wondering if there was a way to store the data in a custom audio worklet for further processing on the client side, ie turning it into a WAV file? I've seen that it's possible to output an audio stream to a `MediaRecorder`, but that results in the creation of lossy audio via the ogg codec. If possible, I would like access to the raw PCM data from the worklet processor so I can encode it as WAV or another lossless format.

My hunch is that this can be accomplished by attaching something to the global audio scope and retrieving it from the audio context, but I'm not sure. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question, I see that there is now the possibility to use PCM as a codec, ie in https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/. This is unfortunately undocumented in most major web audio documentation, but as it exists in several modern browsers, it is good enough for my needs!